# Assigning the return values from a function to a block's arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a column in a table whose value and CSS class are supposed to vary based on a boolean. The initial version I had was:

```
%td.sba{ class: product.sold_by_amazon? ? :yes : :no }= product.sold_by_amazon? ? '✔' : '–'
```

I wanted to remove the repeated boolean lookup, and ended up with:

```
- Proc.new{ |p| yield ([{ yes: :✔ }, { no: :– }].try( :[], product.sold_by_amazon? ? 0 : 1 )) }.call do |sold, text|
  %td.sba{ class: sold }= text
```

Is there a less convoluted way to do that?

Also, a simpler solution is to generate the text using CSS `content`.

Comment: Code in the view is often a smell of an X/Y problem. Why isn't this handled as a virtual attribute in your model?

Answer (score 0):

you could just move this logic to helper, and write something like:

```
def sold_by_amazon_row(product)
  if product.sold_by_amazon?
    content_tag :td, '✔', class: "sba yes"
  else
    content_tag :td, '-', class: "sba no"
  end
end
```

and then:

```
= sold_by_amazon_row(product)
```

---

of course you could add this method to original classes like:

```
class TrueClass
  def yes_no
    "Yes"
  end

  def sign
    "+"
  end
end

class FalseClass
  def yes_no
    "No"
  end

  def sign
    "-"
  end
end
```

or use monkey patching and write something like:

```
class << bool
  def yes_no
    self ? "Yes" : "No"
  end

  def sign
    self ? "+" : "-"
  end
end
```

but you shouldn't make an elephant out of a fly, also just as my opition even using simple `?:` looks more clear than:

```
Proc.new{ |p| yield ([{ yes: :✔ }, { no: :– }].try( :[], product.sold_by_amazon? ? 0 : 1 )) }.call do |sold, text|
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you care about the "repeated boolean lookup"?

If it's an efficiency thing, then memoize the result of the predicate function `.sold_by_amazon?`

```
#product.rb
def sold_by_amazon?
  return false if @sold_by_amazon == false
  @sold_by_amazon || = calculate_if_sold_by_amazon
end

private
def calculate_if_sold_by_amazon
  # some expensive calculation to work out whether or not this is sold by Amazon
end
```

Comment: you could remove one answer;)

Comment: grrrr... picnic - it was supposed to be an edit - ended as a double-post :-/